# Using OPENROWSET to export dataset into specific range in Excel sheet

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, export-to-excel, openrowset

I would like to export data from sql server into an Excel sheet. The sheet is structured and has more than one table.

Is there a way to specify an export range or is it limited to sheet only?

```
insert into opendatasource(
    'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
    'Data Source=Mypath\MyFile.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0')...[MySheet$]
```

And I need specify something like:

```
[MySheet$].MySpecificTable or
MySheet$MySpecificTable or
MySheet$I4:M8
```

[image: excel screenshot]

I don't want use the export wizard - this task should be automated. I know how to do this in C# or SSIS or VBA, but I want know how to do this via `OPENDATASOURCE` or `OPENROWSET`.

Comment: You need to use C# for this. Any specific reason why you want to achieve this via openrowset ?

Comment: I'm only interested (because this should be handled by users withou security context to access server side - without deploys, but with access to sql server databases). In SSIS syntax MySheet$I4:M8 works fine, so i'm looking for similar solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **no way** how to do this via opendatasource/openrowset...

Opendatasource is half-unproduced functionality. It's probably not done to work with data but only for ad-hoc connections.